# C# xUnit Mock SetUp method returns null when Test run

Tags: c#, xunit, .net-5, fixtures

I am working on .NET 5 automation test, I have created mock object using fixture which I can in debugging and configure setup method for mock return but getting null output, not sure what I am missing. In same test I have create mock method for other classes and it did worked.

```
var paidParkingTransactionsMoq = fixture.CreateMany<PaidParkingTransactionClientModel>(5);

fixture.Customize<PaidParkingTransactionClientModel>(c => c
            .With(x => x.SiteId, siteId)
            .With(x => x.Vrm, vrm)
            .With(x => x.TransactionFromDateUtc, exemptionStartDateTime)
            .With(x => x.TransactionToDateUtc, exemptionEndDateTime)
        );

var paidParkingTransactionMoq = fixture.CreateMany<PaidParkingTransactionClientModel>(1);

var PayByPhoneTransactions = paidParkingTransactionsMoq.Union(paidParkingTransactionMoq).ToList();

payByPhoneLoopupMoq.Setup(x => x.GetLatestTransactionAfterSync(machineMoq.ToList(), vrm)).ReturnsAsync(PayByPhoneTransactions);
```

Actual class

```
public class PayByPhoneExtensions
{
 public async Task<List<PaidParkingTransactionClientModel>> GetLatestTransactionAfterSync(List<MachineDataView> machines, string vrm)
 {
       //remain code here
 }
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

found the answer

```
payByPhoneLoopupMoq.Setup(x => x.GetLatestTransactionAfterSync(It.IsAny<List<MachineDataView>>(), vrm)).ReturnsAsync(PayByPhoneTransactions);
```